# Preprocess conditional arch/make file to get non-conditional file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a conditional makefile (well, actually I am dealing with the arch file that will be called when invoking make) that is quite involved and I would like to preprocess it to get rid of all the 'ifeq', 'ifneq' parts that only worsen the readability, in order to see better what is being actually done. I tried doing

```
make -n -d
```

where I get the whole calls to the compiler, but that is also a pain since then I need to separate manually all the flags. I just want to get my nice makefile with my separate FLAGS, DFLAGS, LIBS sentences etc etc.

(My apologies if this has been said anywhere, but I am unable to find it).
Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately there's no feature of GNU make which will do this.  You can use `make -n -p` to show the contents of the final database but it won't be in the same order.  You definitely don't want to use `-d`, IMO.